# How do I access the variable in componentWillMount()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to set a global style variable from the `componentWillMount()` but I am not able to do that. When I am logging the variable it says undefined.

```
export default class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      postImageUri: {
        uri: this.props.postImageUri
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    Image.getSize(this.props.postImageUri, (width, height) => {
      ...
      styles.postImage.height = height
      styles.postImage.width = Dimensions.get('window').width
      console.log(styles.postImage.height)           //Undefined
      console.log(styles.postImage.width)            //Undefined
      ...
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Image source={this.state.postImageUri} style={styles.postImage}/>
      </View>
  }
}

val styles = StyleSheet.create({
  postImage: {
    height: 0,
    width: 0
  }
})
```

Comment: The function Image.getSize doesn't seem to be defined. If it's supposed to do a fetch to get some data, then it seems to be a little off.

Would you care to explain more what you're trying to do? I would suggest you like into how AJAX calls are made if you want to fetch data when the component will mount.

Comment: @LeandroSoares It's a RN method https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#getsize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of mutating the style, you should store the height in state:

```
state = {
  height: null,
};

componentDidMount() {
  Image.getSize(this.props.postImageUri, (width, height) => {
    this.setState({ height });
  });
}
```

Then use style composition to apply the height from the state:

```
<Image 
  source={this.state.postImageUri} 
  style={[styles.postImage, { height: this.state.height } ]}
/>
```

Your width computation is synchronous so you can set it directly in style:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  postImage: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the style in state instead of storing in a global variable. This way the component will itself figure out whenever the state is changed and component will re-render.

You can change the state using `this.setState({stateName: someValue});`.

Comment: But the styles management would be better if I keep all the styles in an object and then referencing it whenever needed. I was also thinking to use react-native-nested-stylesheet for the same.    
Is there any better way to define styles other than inline?

Comment: @Paradox then do the above calculation in the `render()` method with style stored in the same.